# How to gzip each file separately inside a folder and then if successful delete the original file

Tags: bash, gzip

I use the following command for zipping each file in a folder separately:

```
for file in *; do gzip "$file"; done
```

But it keeps the original files. I want to know if there is a way to delete the files automatically after they're successfully gzipped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand the issue you're having.  According to the [gzip man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?gzip):

> Whenever possible, each file is replaced by one  with the extension .gz, while keeping the same ownership modes, access and modification times.

My only guess is you're having permissions issues.  Make sure you're logged in as the owner of the file that you are gzipping.  However, in the gzip version on my machine, I get an obvious `Operation not permitted` warning when I try to gzip a file that I don't own.  The operation still succeeds, but it's clear what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to @Tim Pote for the likely cause.

Beware of `for` loops when you're dealing with files, though: if a file name contains an embedded space, it will be treated as two separate file names.  You can avoid this by using `find` like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.gz' -exec gzip "{}" \;
```

This finds all regular files in the current directory that aren't already compressed, then invokes `gzip` on each one individually.  The curly braces (`{}`) are replaced by the file name, and the quotes ensure that spaces are handled properly.

Comment: I get `-bash: *.gz: Command not found. ` and if I replace the backticks with apostropes, I get argument list too long error

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the typo. Good catch, 4 years later. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have several thousand files, to prevent an "argument list too long" error use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.gz' | while read file; do
    gzip "$file"
done
```